# Cannot install mayavi/vtk with pip3 install due "Failed building wheel for mayavi" but install works on virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, vtk, mayavi, python-wheel

When I try to install mayavi normally with

```
pip3 install mayavi
```

it gives the error

```
ERRROR: Failed building wheel for mayavi
```

and does not install. Strangely, if I create the virtual environment with

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

get into the virtualenv then pip3 install, no error arise and everything works perfectly. I think it's some issue with the wheel setup working with vtk but I don't know enough about it to figure out why the issue is caused. If I could get a help on how to proceed to nail down the cause of the issue, that would be fantastic. I've posted a full error for reference below. In case someone is asking why I don't just use venv, I want to put the entire environment to work in docker container without venv.

````
rob@taqueria:/# pip3 install mayavi
Collecting mayavi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/ea/eb808cb4df8f92bc4d9f9a1ef14566b9b5d60370e6ecbaf9061cdae335fa/mayavi-4.7.1.tar.bz2
Requirement already satisfied: apptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: envisage in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyface>=6.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (6.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: traits>=4.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: traitsui>=6.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (6.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: vtk in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mayavi) (8.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: configobj in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from apptools->mayavi) (5.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apptools->mayavi) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from envisage->mayavi) (39.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi
  Building wheel for mayavi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-w7bpqedu --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vtk/vtkOpenGLKit.py", line 5, in <module>
      from .vtkOpenGLKitPython import *
  ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
      **config
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/setup.py", line 268, in run
      build_tvtk_classes_zip()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/setup.py", line 254, in build_tvtk_classes_zip
      gen_tvtk_classes_zip()
    File "tvtk/setup.py", line 83, in gen_tvtk_classes_zip
      from tvtk.code_gen import TVTKGenerator
    File "/tmp/pip-install-855msxfa/mayavi/tvtk/code_gen.py", line 10, in <module>
      import vtk_module as vtk
    File "tvtk/vtk_module.py", line 15, in <module>
      from vtk import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vtk/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
      from .vtkOpenGLKit import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vtk/vtkOpenGLKit.py", line 9, in <module>
      from vtkOpenGLKitPython import *
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkOpenGLKitPython'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mayavi
  Running setup.py clean for mayavi
Failed to build mayavi```
````

Comment: Do you have this package `libglvnd-dev` installed? `sudo apt install libglvnd-dev`

Comment: Same problem but on windows 10